# Sqlite: Database mirror with Human readable tables

Tags: database, sqlite

I have database which contains many relation tables. In all tables referencing is done using guids(primary key) as foreign keys. Hence it is very difficult to make changes inside database directly without any client application.

I wanted to make exact copy of database with same tables but rather than using guid (primary key) use human reable column as foreign key which is unquie too.

What should be my approach ? and how to link these two dbs? so when i make changes in human reable db those changes are reflected in main db(one with guids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Ended up creating two databases. Both have same structure and relationships.
the only difference is the data in foreign key columns.
DB 'A' - all foreign key columns data are Guids.
DB 'B' - all foreign key columns data are human-readable

2) Attached 'A' to 'B'. 
3) Created (Insert update delete) triggers for all tables in 'B' to reflect any changes made in 'A' and vice versa.

PS: MANAGING TRIGGERS WHEN STRUCTURE UPDATES IS A BIG HEADACHE

ADVANTAGES: I can open DB 'B' looking at column data I can understand the row and make necessary changes.